# not opening the popup in window

Tags: javascript, html, css

my this link is not opening the new link in a pop up It is opening on the new tab .i want it to open in a proper pop up

```
<button class="button button1" onclick=" window.open('test1.php')" style ="padding-top=20px"> Generater Receipt</button>
```

Comment: That isn’t really up to you any more these days, I have my browser configured to _always_ open new tabs instead of free-floating popups.

Comment: You can _try_ to influence the behavior via the third parameter, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open - but there is no guarantee it will work the way you want everywhere.

Comment: Low effort post... What have you tried? Code snippets?

Comment: Try with JavaScript You can refer [load a php file into a popup...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041911/10403049)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to open it in popup

```
<button class="button button1" onclick=" window.open('test1.php' ,'_blank')" style ="padding-top=20px"> Generater Receipt</button>
```